# Explain this math statement

Tags: notation

Quoting a paragraph from Timothy Grover's The Princeton Companion To Mathematics,

> (9) ∀n ∃m     (m>n) ∧ (m ∈ P).
>
> In words, this says that for every n we can find some m that is both
> bigger than n and a prime. If we wish to unpack sentence (9) further,
> we could replace the part m ∈ P by
>
> (10) ∀a,b  ab = m ⇒ ((a = 1) ∨ (b = 1)).

Here in (m ∈ P), Timothy meant m belongs to prime.  How is (m ∈ P) be rewritten as sentence (10). As I understand when sentence (10) explained in english, for all a and b, a*b=m implies that either a =1, b=1 or both being 1. So a=4, b=1 satisfies sentence (10). a*b = m = 1*4 = 4 is not a prime number. This is clearly wrong. What am I missing here.

Comment: You are missing the fact that $a=2$ and $b=2$ makes "$(ab=4)\implies((a=1)\vee(b=1))$" false.

Comment: Must be true for *any* factorization $ab$ of $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is that $a,b$ is preceded by $\forall$, meaning that for all possible pairs of (presumably positive) integers $a, b$ such that their product equals $m$, either $a = 1$, or $b = 1$.  This prevents $m = 4$ because there exists the choice $a = b = 2$ for which $ab = 4$ but neither $a = 1$ nor $b = 1$.

Comment: Thank you, but I still have questions. Let statement (1) be ab = m . Let (2) be ((a = 1) ∨ (b = 1)). The statement (1)  ⇒  (2) means what? Is (1) due to (2)? vice versa?. I think thats where I am confused. Explaining each sub part of the statement would help me to understand better. Thanks again!

Comment: @KarthickS The meaning of the double arrow is "implies."  In other words, the translation of the statement is, "for all (positive integers) $a, b$, $ab = m$ implies either $a = 1$ or $b = 1$."

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the fact that it has to hold for any $a$ and $b$ ... so if you just find one example this is not sufficient.

For example, for $m=4$, you have $a=2$ and $b=2$ which is a counterexample, so $(10)$ is not true for $m=4$.

Comment: Thank you, please check my comment on heropup answer. I am still unclear and more explanations will help.